# Visibility converter doesn't work even though binding works

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am trying to use the visibility converter from MvvmCross but for some reason the visibility of the view that I'm  trying to edit doesn't change at all.

I am using fluent binding in order to bind the element:

```
var set = this.CreateBindingSet<NextStopFragment, NextStopViewModel>();
set.Bind(Header).For(v => v.Visibility).To(vm => vm.LayoutVisibility_0).WithConversion("Visibility");
set.Apply();
```

And this is the code from my viewmodel:

```
private bool _layoutVisibility_0 = false;
public bool LayoutVisibility_0
{
    get { return _layoutVisibility_0; }
    set { _layoutVisibility_0 = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => LayoutVisibility_0); }
}

public override void Prepare(Parameter parameter)
{
    LayoutVisibility_0 = true;
}
```

This is the layout of the view that I'm binding (please note that I am restricted to using fluent binding on this):

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/NextStopHeader"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/border_bottom_gray"
android:paddingLeft="15dp"
android:paddingRight="15dp"
android:paddingTop="8dp"
android:paddingBottom="8dp"
android:visibility="gone"/>
```

For the moment I am only trying to make the LinearLayout visible from the start, but it doesn't work. The binding works (I think) because the property gets updated correctly every time I am trying to edit it, but even if the property is set to true, the view remains "gone".

Have I missed something? Do I need to add anything else? Please note that this is ALL the code that I'm using for editing the visibility.

Comment: Does the binding work when set via the axml? `local:MvxBind="Visibility Visibility(LayoutVisibility_0)"`

Comment: I've just tried and the problem still persists. By the way, apparently the binding works, but the converter doesn't do its job.

Comment: I have the exact same problem with ProgressBar. In my case Gone/Hidden was not an issue so I could bind to Visible instead. But I would like to handle this in a better way.